# Laravel: Upsert multiple records with many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following code I'm using to insert/update groups in my database.

```
$data = array();
$group_users = array();

foreach ($groups as $group) {

    foreach ($group->users as $user) {
        $group_users[$group->id][$user->id] = array(
            'main_user' => strtolower($user->meta->role) === 'leader' ? 1 : 0
        );
    }

    $data[$group->id] = array(
        'name' => $group->name,
        'client_id' => $this->client->id,
        'description' => $group->description,
        'type' => $group->type,
        'external_id' => $group->id
    );
}

foreach(array_chunk($data, 1000) as $chunk) {
    Group::upsert(
        $chunk,
        ['client_id', 'external_id'],
        ['name', 'description', 'type']
    );
}

$client_groups = Group::where('client_id', $this->client->id)->get();

foreach ($client_groups as $group) {
    $client_groups->where('external_id', $group->id)->first()->users()->sync($group_users[$group->id]);
}
```

This works fine, but what I really want to do is include the relationship data between the groups and the users (many-to-many) - `$group->users`

I know how to do this if I'm using updateOrInsert for one record at a time, but can I achieve this when saving batches of data?

Comment: would the sync() method work for you on your group model?   What is your many to many relationship?

Comment: I'm currently using the sync method outside of the upsert. I've added this to the code. Where do I add this to the upsert method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use upsert for many-to-many relation if you create pivot model for your relation table. After creating it just use upsert as usual. You'll only need to prepare your data first (basically ids pairs array). And don't forget to add unique index on your pivot table.

Your pivot model (let's say your pivot table named `user_group`):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class UserGroup extends Pivot
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'group_id',
        'user_id'
    ];
}
```

It may look like this

```
// $usersGroups = [[1,2], [1,3]]
UserGroup::upsert(
  $usersGroups,
  ['user_id', 'group_id']
);
```

Comment: I've added the code I've got for adding the relationship data. I'm just not sure what I need to do with this in the upsert method.

Comment: You cannot add many-to-many relation data to the Group upsert. `sync` method still require you to iterate through groups to sync each entity. If you really want to do everything using mass upserts - please, see example I've added to my answer.